# Scraping hidden emails with BS4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm working with Python and BS4, trying to retrieve email addresses from websites. However, on some of the pages I'm working on, the emails look like this:

```
<a href="mailto:%77e%6ed%65l%6c_%73a%79@%6eo%74e%73.%6b1%32.%68i%2eu%73">Firstname Lastname</a>
```

Is there a way to extract an email address from this?

Comment: Decode the url encoding...

Comment: It's not UTF-8, it's URL encoding. Google it, and how to decode it in Python.

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea what that was called.

Answer (score 1):

While you using `beautifulsoup` and maybe `requests` you can select the `<a>` and decode like this:

```
requests.utils.unquote(soup.find('a').get('href')).split(':')[-1]
```

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<a href="mailto:%77e%6ed%65l%6c_%73a%79@%6eo%74e%73.%6b1%32.%68i%2eu%73">Firstname Lastname</a>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html) 
requests.utils.unquote(soup.find('a').get('href')).split(':')[-1]
```

##### Output

```
wendell_say@notes.k12.hi.us
```

Comment: also with `urllib.parse.unquote(email)`